# unable to find native module in /proc/.../maps for Android NDK app

Tags: android, mobile, reverse-engineering

I made a sample NDK hello world application via Android Studio (simply used the one straight from the wizard). Everything works fine and I'm able to communicate with the native module (hello_ndk.so). The generated code is as follows:

```
package com.example.hello_ndk

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.TextView
import com.example.hello_ndk.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        // Example of a call to a native method
        binding.sampleText.text = stringFromJNI()
        Log.i("TEST", stringFromJNI());
    }

    /**
     * A native method that is implemented by the 'hello_ndk' native library,
     * which is packaged with this application.
     */
    external fun stringFromJNI(): String

    companion object {
        // Used to load the 'hello_ndk' library on application startup.
        init {
            System.loadLibrary("hello_ndk")
        }
    }
}
```

As I mentioned, everything works fine in terms of the call to JNI and back etc. I'm using SDK 31 and running on an Android 12 emulator. I adb into the emulator (as root) and attempt to manually find the loaded module like so:

```
emulator64_x86_64:/ # cat /proc/13433/maps | grep hello_ndk.so
1|emulator64_x86_64:/ # cat /proc/13433/maps | grep native-lib.so
1|emulator64_x86_64:/ # ps -A | grep -i hello_ndk
u0_a108      13433   372 13728128 162904 do_epoll_wait      0 S com.example.hello_ndk
```

Shouldnt the hello_ndk.so module be seen in the process's maps view since it is loaded (since I'm using it)? Why doesnt my search yield results (the loaded .so file)?